# Running `tsc` on project using Webpack throws errors not seen in webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

I use Webpack to build my Typescript project. However, webpack is slowing down as my project gets bigger.

I want to break typescript checking out into a separate process using `tsc`.

However, when I run `tsc` on my project I receive Type declaration errors that I don't get when using the `ts-loader` for Webpack.

I think this is cause by how typescript and webpack differ in importing modules.

> Modules resolution:
>   It's very important to be aware that this plugin uses typescript's,
>   not webpack's modules resolution. It means that you have to setup
>   tsconfig.json correctly. For example if you set files:
>   ['./src/someFile.ts'] in tsconfig.json, this plugin will check only
>   someFile.ts for semantic errors. It's because of performance. The goal
>   of this plugin is to be as fast as possible. With typescript's module
>   resolution we don't have to wait for webpack to compile files (which
>   traverses dependency graph during compilation) - we have a full list
>   of files from the begin.
>   https://github.com/Realytics/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin#modules-resolution

Here are some example errors:

```
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:143:13 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts:8719:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts:8745:18 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'geolocation' must be of type 'Geolocation', but here has type 'GeolocationStatic'.
node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts:203:13 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require'.
node_modules/rxjs/scheduler/VirtualTimeScheduler.d.ts:24:15 - error TS2416: Property 'work' in type 'VirtualAction<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'AsyncAction<T>'.
```

more details here: https://gist.github.com/IanEdington/b1567b2cabae262eac8a6ef6a4206d4b

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@qDot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4040754/qdot) for figuring this out: https://github.com/Realytics/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/issues/116#issuecomment-385286544

> This is a problem with node and typescript libraries colliding. See:
>
> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23769
>
> Quick fix: Back down to `@types/node v9.6.7` until v10 can be fixed.